# Remove lines that contain the same first word

Tags: bash

I have two text files, `1.txt` and `2.txt`. If the first word of any line on `2.txt` is on file `1.txt`, I want to delete it from `1.txt`. For example:

**1.txt:**

```
1 HI
2 HELLO
FIND 5
RESUME 1
```

**2.txt:**

```
1
FIND
```

The result would be:

**3.txt:**

```
2 HELLO
RESUME 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but I am assuming there is no problem with modifying 1.txt directly too.

```
while read line 
do

    sed -E -i "/^$line/ s/.*/THISISAREMOVEDLINE1234567890/g" 1.txt


done < <(cat 2.txt )

grep -v 'THISISAREMOVEDLINE1234567890' 1.txt > final_output.txt
```

Let me know if it works for you. :)

```
ubuntu$ cat final_output.txt
2 HELLO
RESUME 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JOIN="$(cat 2.txt | tr -d "\r"| xargs -n 1 printf "%s " | sed 's/|/\\|/g;s/ $//;s/ /|/g')"

cat 1.txt | grep -vE "^($JOIN)"
> 2 HELLO
> RESUME 1
```

Explanation:

First transform the first file into a bar seperated list so it looks like this

```
"1|FIRST"
```

I do that by using tr to remove in '\r' if you happen to be windows this will clean up some things (Yes bash can run on windows) and then I use xargs to reformat each line as a space seperated list. Then sed removes the trailing spaces, transforms the others to bars. Also note I escape existing bars first so you don't get weird behavior if a toke happens to include a bar. I.E.:

```
1
FIRST|ONE
TACO
```

becomes

```
"1|FIRST\|ONE|TACO"
```

Now pass this into grep with -v to tell grep to remove matches, and -E to allow extended regex support which allows us to use bar to specify groups of matches.

```
cat 1.txt | grep -vE "^(1|FIRST)"
```

will remove any file starting with '1' or 'FIRST'.